# Calling unique attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to select the below attribute 'time' in javascript in the same fashion as getElementById?

```
<div time="1537311600000" data-tooltip="" class="day toMonth  valid">19</div>
```

Comment: Yes: `[time=1537311600000]` would be the selector you'd use with `document.querySelector`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access it with [getAtribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)

```js
window.onload = function(){

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute("time"));
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute("data-tooltip"));

}
```

```html
<div time="1537311600000" data-tooltip="" class="day toMonth  valid">19</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` allows you to select on any attribute you like:

```js
const timeToMatch = 1537311600000
const results = document.querySelectorAll(`[time="${timeToMatch}"]`)

console.dir(results)
```

```html
<div time="1537311600000" data-tooltip="" class="day toMonth  valid">19</div>
```